# Mysql2::Error: Operand should contain 1 column(s):

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, duplicates

I am trying to select all the duplicate properties in my rails controller. I want to compare each property's address by street and return the result to me to display on the page.

What I have tried:

```
@conflicts = Property.where("SELECT street, COUNT(street) FROM properties GROUP BY street HAVING COUNT(street) >1")
```

and this is the error I receive:

```
Mysql2::Error: Operand should contain 1 column(s): SELECT `properties`.* FROM `properties` WHERE (SELECT street, COUNT(street) FROM properties GROUP BY street HAVING COUNT(street) >1)
```

I understand there are a number of questions that have been asked that are similar to mine, but I need back the entire array of properties with all their information, not just the street and not just the count of how many duplicates there are. Thanks!

*UPDATE:* Also tried:

```
@conflicts = Property.where("SELECT street FROM properties GROUP BY street HAVING count(street) > 1")
```

which gave me:

```
Mysql2::Error: Subquery returns more than 1 row: SELECT `properties`.* FROM `properties` WHERE (SELECT street FROM properties GROUP BY street HAVING count(street) > 1)
```

What I want is to have a table with something like this

```
property_id |         street |    state |   zip
          1 | 123 test drive | Arkansas | 12345
          2 | 123 test drive |     Iowa | 45632
          3 | 999 not avenue | Delaware | 55556
```

and it return properties 1 and 2.

Comment: how do you expect the entire info to be displayed since data has to be removed of similar properties with matching street name. Show us an example what would be target..

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the RoR query builder syntax, but the raw query you want is:

```
SELECT street, COUNT(*)
FROM properties
GROUP BY street
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

Comment: Yes that is exactly what I thought! I'm guessing this means that it is an issue with the RoR builder, like you said. Thanks!

Comment: No, the issue is what you wrote. You shouldn't use `.where()`.